rename file in Laravel Controller
How we  rename in this code in laravel controller?
I want to rename our file need to add prefix and suffix with timestamp i.e. FAS_12062024.png.
Now we get something like this "bRpBIKjkY4VCiEbH7jVVS6JjEv7ffs9f7CzuOhXC" file name in laravel 10.
elseif ($row->type == 'file') {
                                if ($row->subtype == "fineuploader") {
                                    $fileSize = number_format($row->max_file_size_mb / 1073742848, 2);
                                    $fileLimit = $row->max_file_size_mb / 1024;
                                    if ($fileSize < $fileLimit) {
                                        $values = [];
                                        $value = explode(',', $request->input($row->name));
                                        foreach ($value as $file) {
                                            $values[] = $file;
                                        }
                                        $row->value = $values;
                                    } else {
                                        return response()->json(['is_success' => false, 'message' => __("Please upload maximum $row->max_file_size_mb MB file size.")], 200);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if ($row->file_extention == 'pdf') {
                                        $allowedFileExtension = ['pdf', 'pdfa', 'fdf', 'xdp', 'xfa', 'pdx', 'pdp', 'pdfxml', 'pdxox'];
                                    } else if ($row->file_extention == 'image') {
                                        $allowedFileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'];
                                    } else if ($row->file_extention == 'excel') {
                                        $allowedFileExtension = ['xlsx', 'csv', 'xlsm', 'xltx', 'xlsb', 'xltm', 'xlw'];
                                    }
                                    $requiredextention = implode(',', $allowedFileExtension);
                                    $fileSize = number_format($row->max_file_size_mb / 1073742848, 2);
                                    $fileLimit = $row->max_file_size_mb / 1024;
                                    if ($fileSize < $fileLimit) {
                                        if ($row->multiple) {
                                            if ($request->hasFile($row->name)) {
                                                $values = [];
                                                $files =$request->file($row->name);
                                                foreach ($files as $file) {
                                                    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                                    $check = in_array($extension, $allowedFileExtension);
                                                    if ($check) {
                                                        if ($extension == 'csv') {
                                                            $name = \Str::random(40) . '.' . $extension;
                                                            $file->move(storage_path() . '/app/form-values/' . $form->id, $name);
                                                            $values[] = 'form-values/' . $form->id . '/' . $name;
                                                        } else {
                                                            $path = Storage::path("form-values/$form->id");
                                                            $fileName = $file->store('form-values/' . $form->id);
                                                            if (!file_exists($path)) {
                                                                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                                                                chmod($path, 0777);
                                                            }
                                                            if (!file_exists(Storage::path($fileName))) {
                                                                mkdir(Storage::path($fileName), 0777, true);
                                                                chmod(Storage::path($fileName), 0777);
                                                            }
                                                            $values[] = $fileName;
                                                        }

                                                              

how do we rename upload file in this above code. except that "csv"

Do you mean like this $name = "ANYTHING_" . time() . '.' . $extension; ? Sorry, I don't understand the question fully.

$fileName = $file->store('form-values/' . $form->id);    // code is now updated now you able to understand

It should be something like
$name = 'FAS_' . now()->format('dmY') . '.' . $extension;


$fileName = $file->store('form-values/' . $form->id); // we have file name like this and above code we updated

if it help, can u mark my answer up ?
